# What is the proper way to capture a HTTP response with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, integration-testing

I am trying to capture the http response status from a user sign-up.

My code looks like this:

```
  it.only('returns a 400 response if email is taken', async () => {
    await page.goto(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/sign-up`)
    await page.waitFor('input[id="Full Name"]')

    await page.type('input[id="Full Name"]', 'Luke Skywalker')
    await page.type('input[id="Email"]', 'LukeSkywalker@voyage.com')
    await page.type('input[id="Password"]', 'LukeSkywalker123', {delay: 100})
    await page.click('input[type="submit"]', {delay: 1000})

    const response = await page.on('response', response => response)

    console.log('request status', response.status)
    // expect(response).toEqual(400)
  })
```

The docs give an example of intercepting the request and doing things with it:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', request => {
  request.respond({
    status: 404,
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    body: 'Not Found!'
  });
});
```

And I have tried a similar pattern to no avail, along with many other patterns. Everything I do returns the `page`, a huge object with no status on it that I can see. Any help is much appreciated.

**WHAT WORKED:**

thank you to @tomahaug for steering me in the correct direction. My first problem was placement, the listener needs to go be set up before the request is made, I had it just after the request. Makes sense. My biggest issue was assigning the listener to a variable, so that I could call the expect as my last line. Assigning it to a variable caused the `page` to be returned. What I needed to do was just run the test inside the listener. While using `done()` throws and error for me I closed off my test as follows below, the working version of my code:

```
it.only('returns a 400 response if email is taken', async () => {
    await page.goto(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/sign-up`)
    await page.waitFor('input[id="Full Name"]')

    await page.type('input[id="Full Name"]', 'Luke Skywalker')
    await page.type('input[id="Email"]', 'LukeSkywalker@voyage1.com')
    await page.type('input[id="Password"]', 'LukeSkywalker123', {delay: 100})

    await page.on('response', response => {
      if (response.request().method === 'POST' && response.url === `${process.env.USERS_API_DOMAIN}/sessions`) {
        expect(response.status).toEqual(400)
      }
    })

    await page.click('input[type="submit"]', {delay: 1000})
  })

  after(async function () {
    await browser.close()
  })
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Instead of "WHAT WORKED", It's better to add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Your solution still looks like it has a race condition. Since you're using a callback, I'd use `done` instead of `async`, then call `done()` in the callback after the `expect` line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you should do something along those lines. Note the callback function `done`.

What the code does, is that it attaches a listener for responses, then clicks the submit button. When a response is received it checks the status code, asserts it, and terminates the test by calling `done`.

You might want to have an `if`-statement that checks that it is the actual response from your form that you are checking in the callback, as the response handler might emit events for other concurrent requests.

```js
it.only('returns a 400 response if email is taken', () => {
  await page.goto(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/sign-up`)
  await page.waitFor('input[id="Full Name"]')

  await page.type('input[id="Full Name"]', 'Luke Skywalker')
  await page.type('input[id="Email"]', 'LukeSkywalker@voyage.com')
  await page.type('input[id="Password"]', 'LukeSkywalker123', {delay: 100})

  page.on('response', (response) => {
    if (
      response.request().method === 'POST' && 
      response.url === `${process.env.USERS_API_DOMAIN}/sessions`) 
    {
      expect(response.status).toEqual(400)
    }
  })

  await page.click('input[type="submit"]', {delay: 1000})
})
```

I have not tested the code, but it should give you the right idea.

Edit: Adjusted to reflect what worked out in the end.

Comment: Ahhh, I need to set up the listener BEFORE I do the submit, makes sense! I  tried this and it seems things are still a little off. The console.log inside the listener gives me nothing, and the test passes even when I make the `.toEqual(123)` and even when I remove the `if` (just in case). I have found console logs inside listeners have not worked for me with puppeteer, not sure why. When I create a variable, and assign the listener's return to it (returning `response.status`) I can see that again, the entire page is being returned as the status. Got anything? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: I think the reason why the test just passes, is because it never reaches the inside of the handler. I have experienced jest to not respect the `done` callback when the test callback has been specified as `async`.

The handler is still asynchronous even if you put `await` in front of it. It is the action of assigning the handler that returns a promise, not the result of the handler itself. So `var something = await page.on(...)` will not provide you with anything put the page instance reference. I'll try to modify my code.

Comment: I've modified the code, which should either make you see some log statements or see a timeout from the test runner.

Comment: got it! woot woot! I spent my whole day yesterday wrestling with this....the issue, was, as you said... I cannot assign it to a variable, else it returns the whole page. I had no idea! Note, the `done()` threw me big fat errors `(node:54604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: request is not defined` and I had to remove it. But at the end, I got it ;)   Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: also thank you for the explanations, that is super helpful in understanding what was happening

Comment: This code has a race condition which forces you to create an artificial 1 second delay. `done` rather than `async` is the correct way to use callbacks that must run assertions.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to manipulate the request/response, use [`page.setRequestInterception(true)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue) and `page.on`/`page.once` ([as documented](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue)).

However, if all you need is to assert something about the response, the simplest and most idiomatic way to do so is with [`page.waitForResponse`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options):

```
const updateDashboardResponse = await page.waitForResponse(response =>
  response.url().includes('updateDashboard')
);
expect(updateDashboardResponse.status()).toBe(200);
```

This allows test flow to remain linear and avoids ambiguity around closing a test before a `page.on` handler  receives a `response` event.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer (which was also edited into the question) is incorrect. It introduces a race condition due to a 1 second delay added to the click call. At best, this slows down the test suite unnecessarily, and at worst it generates false failures should the request take longer than a second to resolve (unlikely if it's mocked, but it doesn't change the fact that the code is unsafe).

Whenever there's a callback in a Jest test case, the correct way to ensure it's been executed and all assertions depending on it firing have been made without adding artificial delays is to [call `done()` from the callback](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#callbacks). If there is a throw in the callback that makes `done` unreachable, call `done(error)` in the error handler to report the test case failure to Jest.

To do this, you'll need to add `done` as the parameter to the callback passed to the `it`, `test` or `only` function so that it's available in the block. This allows Jest's test runner to treat the test as asynchronous and not to resolve it until `done` is called. Without `done`, the test suite ignores the callback's assertions. `async`/`await` doesn't help because it's a separate asynchronous chain than the callback.

You only need to specify `done` as a parameter or return a promise (`async` implicitly returns a promise), never both. However, you'd still likely want to use `await` for Puppeteer library calls rather than `then`. You can use an `async` IIFE that eventually fires the `done()` call when all assertions have fired to get the best of both worlds.

For example,

```js
it.only('returns a 400 response if email is taken', done => {
  (async () => {
    page.on('response', response => {
      if (response.request().method === 'POST' && 
          response.url === `${process.env.USERS_API_DOMAIN}/sessions`) {
        try { /* try-catch pattern shown for illustration */
          expect(response.status).toEqual(400);
          done();
        } 
        catch (err) {
          done(err);
        }
      }
    });    
    await page.goto(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/sign-up`);
    await page.waitFor('input[id="Full Name"]');
    await page.type('input[id="Full Name"]', 'Luke Skywalker');
    await page.type('input[id="Email"]', 'LukeSkywalker@voyage.com');
    await page.type('input[id="Password"]', 'LukeSkywalker123', {delay: 100});
    await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
  })();
});
```

With this in mind, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58141808/6243352) shows a likely better approach using [`waitForResponse`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) which lets you skip the callback and `done` entirely. The callback to `waitForResponse` is a string URL or function predicate that should return true for the target response that's being waited on:

```js
it.only('returns a 400 response if email is taken', async () => {
  await page.goto(`${process.env.DOMAIN}/sign-up`);
  await page.waitFor('input[id="Full Name"]');
  await page.type('input[id="Full Name"]', 'Luke Skywalker');
  await page.type('input[id="Email"]', 'LukeSkywalker@voyage.com');
  await page.type('input[id="Password"]', 'LukeSkywalker123', {delay: 100});
  const responseP = page.waitForResponse(response =>
    response.request().method === 'POST' && 
    response.url === `${process.env.USERS_API_DOMAIN}/sessions`
  );
  await page.click('input[type="submit"]');
  const response = await responseP;
  expect(response.status).toEqual(400);
});
```

I should also mention `waitFor` is deprecated in favor of `waitForSelector` in the above snippets and that `.url` and `.method` are functions. I haven't verified the above code; it's there to relate to the original post and show the high-level patterns.

---

### Minimal example

#### `index.html`

This is the web page we're testing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Post</button>
    <script>
      document
        .querySelector("button")
        .addEventListener("click", e =>
          fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify({
                title: "foo",
                body: "bar",
                userId: 1,
              }),
              headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
              },
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json))
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### `index.test.js` (`async`/`await` version):

```js
describe("index page", () => {
  it("should respond to POST", async () => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    await page.goto("http://localhost:1234", {waitUntil: "load"});
    const responseP = page.waitForResponse(response =>
      response.request().method() === "POST" &&
      response.url() === url
    );
    await page.click("button");
    const response = await responseP;
    const expectedBody = {
      body: "bar",
      id: 101,
      title: "foo",
      userId: 1,
    };
    expect(await response.json()).toEqual(expectedBody);
  });
});
```

#### `index.test.js` (`then` version):

```js
describe("index page", () => {
  it("should respond to POST", () => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    const expectedBody = {
      body: "bar",
      id: 101,
      title: "foo",
      userId: 1,
    };
    const navP = page.goto("http://localhost:1234", {
      waitUntil: "load",
    });
    const responseP = navP.then(() =>
      page.waitForResponse(
        response =>
          response.request().method() === "POST" &&
          response.url() === url
      )
    );
    return navP
      .then(() => page.click("button"))
      .then(() => responseP)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => expect(body).toEqual(expectedBody));
  });
});
```

#### `index.test.js` (`done` version):

```js
describe("index page", () => {
  it("should respond to POST", done => {
    (async () => {
      const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
      const expectedBody = {
        body: "bar",
        id: 101,
        title: "foo",
        userId: 1,
      };
      await page.setRequestInterception(true);
      page.on("response", async response => {
        if (response.request().method() === "POST" &&
            response.url() === url) {
          try {
            const body = await response.json();
            expect(body).toEqual(expectedBody);
            done();
          }
          catch (err) {
            done(err);
          }
        }
      });
      await page.goto("http://localhost:1234", {
        waitUntil: "load"
      });
      await page.click("button");
    })();
  });
});
```

If you're reusing `page` between tests, remember to remove `page.on` listeners with `page.off`.

Answer (score 1):

`response.url` is a function and you have to call it:

```
response.url()
```

The same is for `response.request().method`:

```
response.request().method()
```

Comment: This is correct. Perhaps Puppeteer's API has changed since the other answers were written, but they should be edited; `url` and `method` are "private" members now, prefixed with an underscore and exposed via getter methods.